# How do I insert HTML boiler plate code in Visual Studio Code on Mac?

Tags: html

I started the coding journey and installed VSC suggested during a YouTube tut.

It seems that all emmet abbreviations are working except for SHIFT + ! which should give me the below.

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas why this is?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get VSCode to expand `!+Tab`, but I agree with you that it should have worked.

However, I've figured out that you can use `html:5+Tab` (or just `!` with the `Emmet: Expand Abbreviation` command) to get a similar result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, @NickMcCurdy!

It appears to once again be different on Mac than on windows.  `HTML:5` worked!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install HTML boilerplate extension from visual studio code extension.

Answer (score 0):

I also use a Mac, I found this issue also when the file did not have a .html extension.

Try creating a new file with a .html extension such as index.html.

Retry the shift ! you did initially and press enter.  The boilerplate should populate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).